# p5js: How do I make my randomly generated circle packing canvas responsive when the window is resized?

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, responsive

When I load the window from a narrow size and make it wider, the added canvas space is white. [[image: narrow to wide resize]]

When I load from a larger window to a smaller size, the canvas stays in the larger size, while HTML and CSS elements respond. In the second picture, the circles are supposed to cut off at the same point as the black rectangle. [[image: wide to narrow]]

I think this is happening because the circles are randomly generated and the layout of them is different whenever the page loads/reloads. Basically, I have to "refresh" the window for the new resized canvas to work. BTW, I tried WindowResized() already.*

```
var font;
var colors;
var bolder;
var canvas;

setup = () => {

    frameRate(2.5);

    function windowResized() {
        resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }

    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    canvas.position(0, 0);
    canvas.style('z-index', '-1');

    colors = [color(255, 0, 0), color(1, 130, 83), color(0, 0, 255), color(255, 255, 0), color(102, 0, 102), color(255, 107, 31)];

    for (var c = 0; c < 1000; c++) {
        var circle = {
            x: random(width),
            y: random(height),
            r: random(90, 15)
        };

        var overlap = false;

        var protection = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
            var other = circles[j];
            var d = dist(circle.x, circle.y, other.x, other.y);
            if (d < circle.r + other.r) {
                overlap = true;
            }
        }

        if (!overlap) {
            circles.push(circle);
        }

        protection++;
        if (protection > 10000) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {

        fill(255, 255, 255);
        strokeWeight(4);
        ellipse(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r * 2, circles[i].r * 2);

    }
}

draw = () => {

    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        if (mouseX > circles[i].x - circles[i].r && mouseX < circles[i].x + circles[i].r && mouseY > circles[i].y - circles[i].r && mouseY < circles[i].y + circles[i].r)

        {
            stroke(0, 0, 0);
            fill(random(colors));
            strokeWeight(4);
            noStroke;
            ellipse(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r * 2, circles[i].r * 2);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining `width` and `height`? ... Without basing your random coords on `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` then how is your draw function supposed to respond dynamically to viewport changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [p5js: How do I make my randomly generated circle packing sketch/canvas responsive when the window is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692767/p5js-how-do-i-make-my-randomly-generated-circle-packing-sketch-canvas-responsiv)